# How can I open file explorer/folder via a button in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set up a small webpage for work that hosts buttons linking to folder or files that is shared over the same network, or opens the file explorer. This is purely for convince, and the devices would be offline so security wouldn't be an issue.

Would this be possible to do via a button on chrome?

Comment: Like to select a file? Or to like see all the contents in the directory?

Comment: Store the files in a folder accessible to the computers on the network (best bet, to the web server itself). Then make a server-side script that reads this folder and presents the contents to the front-end for display.

Comment: @epascarello To see the contents in the directory. Such as hitting button A and it opens up the window explorer showing the contents of the C drive

Comment: Look into `wscript` instead. It's built-into MS Windows (if that's what you're using) and has the features you desire.